# Angular 7 CLI: Unable to create a new app as it throws error

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular7

When using Angular 7 CLI and attempting to create a new Angular App and I get the following error:

> /bin/sh: cnpm: command not found

```
2018-11-04 13:27:17 ⌚  COMPUTER_X in ~/TEK/learn
○ → ng new firebase-auth
? Would you like to add Angular routing? No
? Which stylesheet format would you like to use? CSS
CREATE firebase-auth/README.md (1029 bytes)
....
CREATE firebase-auth/e2e/src/app.po.ts (208 bytes)
/bin/sh: cnpm: command not found
Package install failed, see above.

 2018-11-04 13:27:25 ⌚  COMPUTER_X in ~/TEK/learn
○ →
```

I'm running this on a Mac with the following setup:

```
2018-11-04 13:22:57 ⌚  COMPUTER_X in ~/TEK/learn
○ → npm --version
6.4.1

2018-11-04 13:23:01 ⌚  COMPUTER_X in ~/TEK/learn
○ → ng --version

Angular CLI: 7.0.3
Node: 8.12.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.10.3
@angular-devkit/core         7.0.3
@angular-devkit/schematics   7.0.3
@schematics/angular          7.0.3
@schematics/update           0.10.3
rxjs                         6.3.3
typescript                   3.1.3


2018-11-04 13:23:04 ⌚  COMPUTER_X in ~/TEK/learn
○ → node --version
v8.12.0

2018-11-04 13:23:25 ⌚  COMPUTER_X in ~/TEK/learn
○ →
```

What's the cause of this error? Has anybody encountered this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a interesting thing.
At first, you can see the config of `Angular`:

```
localhost:ng-test near$ ng config -g
We found a global configuration that was used in Angular CLI 1. It has been 
automatically migrated.
{
  "version": 1,
  "cli": {
    "packageManager": "cnpm"
  },
  "newProjectRoot": "./",
  "schematics": {},
  "architect": {},
  "targets": {},
  "projects": {}
}
```

You can see your `cli.packageManager` is `cnpm`.

So there are two ways to fix this problem.

1.install cnpm globally

```
npm install -g cnpm
```

2.change the `cli.packageManager`

```
ng config -g cli.packageManager npm
```

After that, you can check the config again.

```
localhost:ng-test near$ ng config -g
We found a global configuration that was used in Angular CLI 1. It has been 
automatically migrated.
{
  "version": 1,
  "cli": {
    "packageManager": "npm"
  },
  "newProjectRoot": "./",
  "schematics": {},
  "architect": {},
  "targets": {},
  "projects": {}
}
```